# fetch all elements dom jquery

Tags: javascript, jquery

I have 2 classes and I want to fetch them all in the DOM of a page to compare their content text with jQuery. I believe that in JS it is something like:

```js
function myFonction() {
  var item = document.getElementsByClassName("title")[0];
  if (item) {
    for (var i = 0; i < document.getElementsByClassName("title2").length; i++) {
      var content = document.getElementsByClassName("title2")[i].innerHTML.trim();
      if (content == item.innerHTML.trim()) {
        console.log("OK");
      }
    }
  }
}
myFonction();
```

Comment: Do you want every nested node? seems excessive

Comment: There is no jQuery in your code. Can I assume that you will accept jQuery as a solution?

Comment: This smells like a "convert this javascript to jquery for me" question.

Comment: @Arrow sorry i don't understand you
I want to do this to add on a menu an arrow of the current element when the user navigates between the pages

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Since you have tagged jQuery in your answer, I will provide a jQuery-based solution. Things are a little more straightforward because you don't need to make messy for loops.

What you want to do is:

1. Cache/store the inner HTML of the first occurring `.title` element
2. If the `.title` element exists, iterate through all `.title2` elements and compare their inner HTML against the cached one in point #1

I have provided a proof-of-concept example below. Matching elements are highlighted in yellow simply for visual indication.

```js
$(function() {
  var compareTitle = function() {
    var $title = $('.title').first(),
        titleContent = $title.html().trim();
        
    if ($title.length) {
      $('.title2').each(function() {
        if ($(this).html().trim() === titleContent) {
          console.log('OK');
          $(this).css('background-color', 'yellow');
        }
      });
    }
  }
  compareTitle();
});
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<div class="title">This is a title.</div>
<div class="title2">This is not a title.</div>
<div class="title2">This is not a title.</div>
<div class="title2">This is not a title.</div>
<div class="title2">This is a title.</div>
<div class="title2">This is not a title.</div>
<div class="title2">This is not a title.</div>
<div class="title2">This is a title.</div>
<div class="title2">This is not a title.</div>
<div class="title2">This is not a title.</div>
<div class="title2">This is not a title.</div>
<div class="title2">This is not a title.</div>
```

If you want it in native JS, that is also not a problem. It's just a bit hairier when doing the for loops ;) also, you can always leverage `document.querySelectorAll()`.

```js
var compareTitle = function() {
  var title = document.querySelectorAll('.title')[0],
      titleContent = title.innerHTML.trim();

  if (title) {
    var title2 = document.querySelectorAll('.title2');
    for (var i=0; i<title2.length; i++) {
      if (title2[i].innerHTML.trim() === titleContent) {
        console.log('OK');
        title2[i].style.backgroundColor = 'yellow';
      }
    }
  }
}
compareTitle();
```

```html
<div class="title">This is a title.</div>
<div class="title2">This is not a title.</div>
<div class="title2">This is not a title.</div>
<div class="title2">This is not a title.</div>
<div class="title2">This is a title.</div>
<div class="title2">This is not a title.</div>
<div class="title2">This is not a title.</div>
<div class="title2">This is a title.</div>
<div class="title2">This is not a title.</div>
<div class="title2">This is not a title.</div>
<div class="title2">This is not a title.</div>
<div class="title2">This is not a title.</div>
```

Comment: heh, interesting how using jquery to get rid of all those weird pesky loops results in more code that isn't actually easier to read (unless you were familiar with jquery and not the dom api)

Comment: @KevinB While you're commenting, I was updating my answer with a native JS alternative

Comment: @KevinB It does, but he's calling the innerHTML of the first `.title` element at every iteration, which is not very effective. I simply provided a more efficient alternative.

Comment: but, that wasn't the question was it?

Comment: @KevinB What is, then?

Comment: ***Exactly***. It's unclear. We have a close reason for that. No question was actually asked.

Answer (score -1):

use `.getElementsByClassName` for each class. Iterate over the `.get` results and just do if groupA[i] == groupB[i] then do whatever. If you too lazy let me frikin do it for you for a "point". lol